# How do I make a module with the form component?

Tags: magento2.2, forms

I want to know how I can create a module that uses the Form Component. Nothing advanced, I just want to know how to make a simple form that can read and write entries from a database, for example a form where you can register and output users. I can't find any good examples. Any guides or tips are very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Creating Basic simple Module**

First create folder structure

> [Magentoroot]/app/code/Company/Module/

Create files **app/code/Company/Module/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Company/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

creating frontend router configuration file
**app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="routername" frontName="routername">
            <module name="Company_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**2. Creating Table and resource model**

create Setup folder add InstallSchema file
**app/code/Company/Module/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('table_name')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'column1',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'column1'
        )->addColumn(
            'column2',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'column2'
        )->addColumn(
            'column3',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'column3'    
        )->setComment(
            'Your table name'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Model/Mymodel.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model;

class Mymodel extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Mymodel');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Mymodel.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Mymodel extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        // table name and primary key
        $this->_init('table_name', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Mymodel/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Mymodel;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Mymodel', 'Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Mymodel');
        $this->_map['fields']['page_id'] = 'main_table.page_id';
    }

}
```

**3. Creating Controllers**

Here i create two action index and submit
**app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $session;
    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, Session $customerSession )
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // echo "test"; die;
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Submit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $session;
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager )
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Company\Module\Model\Mymodel');
        $model->setData($data);
        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Data Successfully Added.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

**1. Creating layout and templates**

**app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/routername_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Myblock" name="my_first_form" template="index.phtml"  />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml**

```
<h1>My First Form</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/submit') ?>" method="post">

    column1 <input name="column1" type="text">
    column2 <input name="column2" type="text">
    column3 <input name="column3" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Block/Myblock.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Myblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    //add your block files
}
```

Finally Open your terminal goto your magento root path run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you can access you **[Your Magent Root Url]/routername/**

Comment: I get *SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mag2new.test_table' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `test_table`*
 when trying to submit. Any tips?

Comment: table not created , while running setup:upgrade are you get any error?

Comment: Nope, no errors. I did `setup:db-data`, `setup:db-schema` and cleaned the cache as well without any success. Also tried removing the module in the `setup_module` table.