# Magento 2 - InstallSchema.php does not create table

Tags: module, magento2.2, setup-script

I have created a module that has a setup that creates a table for me. However, the table does not exist after installing the module. I don't know why.

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mag2new.formmodule_users' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE formmodule_users

File is: `Setup/InstallSchema.php`

```
namespace Company\FormModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('formmodule_users')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Firstname'
        )->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Lastname'
        )->addColumn(
            'address',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Address'    
        )->setComment(
            'FormModule User Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I've tried `setup:upgrade`, `setup:db-schema:upgrade`, `setup:db-data:upgrade`, `cache:clean` and deleting the record in setup_module. Any tips?

I used this for my module: [How do I make a module with the form component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220191/how-do-i-make-a-module-with-the-form-component)

Comment: Can you paste all other relevant files of your module?

Comment: The files I have created are here:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220191/how-do-i-make-a-module-with-the-form-component . I've only changed the module name to fit my vendor.

Answer (score 1):

try this code checking version

```
namespace Company\FormModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0){
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('formmodule_users')
            )->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'ID'
            )->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable' => true],
                'Firstname'
            )->addColumn(
                'lastname',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable' => true],
                'Lastname'
            )->addColumn(
                'address',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable' => true],
                'Address'    
            )->setComment(
                'FormModule User Table'
            );
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

compare your current module version. for example module.xml

```
<module name="Company_FormModule" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
```

so your current version 2.0.0 you update your version edit **setup_version = "2.0.1"** and InstallSchema.php

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0){
   // your table
}
```

then finally **setup:upgrade** and **cache:clean**

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try , it worked for me ( replace this code in your public function ):

```
$table = $setup->getConnection()
    ->newTable($setup->getTable('formmodule_users'))
    ->addColumn(
        'id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'name',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Firstname'
    )->addColumn(
        'lastname',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Lastname'
    )->addColumn(
        'address',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Address'    
    )->setComment("FormModule User Table");
$setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$setup->endSetup();
```

Comment: Hmm.. this did not work for me. I replaced the code, upgraded, cleaned cache and removed the record in setup_module. Did my code work for you or not?

Comment: okay, when you installed your module first time did you add this schema install or first you added your module and then added install schema ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I ran setup:upgrade after all the files were added to my module.

Comment: my mean, when you installed the module was schema part of that module or you added schema later ? disable your module, ( also delete entry from your app/etc/config.php and delete your module entry from setup_module table. And then install your module

Comment: The schema is a part of the module, I added the link to the guide in my question I was following if you'd like to review the code. I deleted the entry in config.php and in setup_module, but still the same error.

Comment: "i deleted entry in config.php and in setup_module" and did you run setup:upgrade , compilation and deployment commands and it didn't work right ? because my point was delete module refrences from all above locations and install your module again or may be you also need to change version of module i.e 2.0.0 to 2.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75451/discussion-between-oscar-and-naveed).